# Linq convert a Method Syntax to Query Expression

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Recently I wrote this query with Linq (Method Syntax), notes: 
 `g.CmsContents` is a Navigatiola Property.

I would like to know how to rewrite this code as a **Linq Query Expression** if it is possible.

```
var myGroupsTypesList = from g in context.CmsGroupsTypes
                        where g.CmsContents.Any(x => x.ContentId == myContentId)
                        select g;
```

Any idea? Thanks for your support :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's already a query expression. If you mean you want to convert the `Any` part to another query expression - you can't. There's no query expression support for `Any`.

If you actually meant it the other way round, your query is equivalent to:

```
var myGroupsTypesList = context.CmsGroupsTypes
          .Where(g => g.CmsContents.Any(x => x.ContentId == myContentId));
```

Comment: Thanks Jon for your comment, so for my understanding if I would like convert the Any part I should not use the Navigational Property? Correct? In that case I should use a Join? Once again thanks for your time on this!

Comment: @GibboK: You *could* use a join... but why not just stick with it as it is? There's no point in avoiding using everything which isn't available in query expression form.

Comment: I understand your point, just try to learn different way to get the same result, so I can learn more about Linq. Thanks for now